# Convert 3D numpy array to new array of 0 and 1 based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy

Been scratching my head quite a lot with this. I have a large (14M) 3D numpy array of integers that I want to duplicate into a same-sized array but populated with 0s and 1s based on multiple conditions of the integers in the initial array. I've tried several options, all shown below, but no success.

In my examples, I want everything that is equal to 87 or 88 in my original atlasarray to equal 1 in my new array (heartPETarray) but I want to reuse this code for additional conditions later, sometimes with single conditions and sometimes with up to 5 matches of integer.

This initial attempt was a midway house to convert everything to 0 that wasn't 87 or 88, but I got the error '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'

```
heartPETarray = atlasarray.copy
heartPETarray[(heartPETarray < 87) | (heartPETarray > 88)] = 0
```

I tried using where with one condition with the intent to add additional conditions later but when I print heartPETarray I get 0 (one instance of the number)

```
heartPETarray = atlasarray.copy
heartPETarray = np.where(heartPETarray == 87, 1, 0)
```

I thought logical_and might be my saviour but I get a similar error as above with the '>' not supported.

```
heartPETarray = atlasarray.copy
heartPETarray = np.logical_and(heartPETarray>86, heartPETarray<89)
```

I've also tried a few more things over the course of the morning, but I can't really remember what I have or haven't tried now and I'm going around in circles through the same webpages and online resources.

Thank you

Comment: what do you get when you try `type(heartPETarray)`?

Comment: OMG, I'm such an idiot. I was missing the () after copy. Popping them back in appears to have made at least the logical_and work now (at first glance)